# Please explain the functionality of select max(...) ... group by in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I appreciate that this may appear to many as a dum question but I cannot find a clear explanation anywhere as to what the effect of "group by" has on a select max(...) from SQL statement.

I have the following data (there is another column image of type mediumblob which is not shown):

```
id  title                      test_id 

1  bomb                             0 
2  Soft watch                       2 
3  Dali                             1 
4  Narciss                          1 
5  The Woman In Green               0 
6  A summer in Vetheuil             0 
7  Artist's Garden                  2 
8  Beech Forest                     2 
9  Claude Monet                     0
```

I know if I perform

```
select max(id) from images 
where image is not null;
```

I get the max value of id i.e.:

```
max(id) 

9
```

However can someone please explain what is happening when I perform

```
select max(id), title, test_id 
from images 
where image is not null 
group by id;
```

I find that the max(id) serves no useful purpose (results shown below)?

```
  max(id)  title                      test_id 

  1  bomb                              0 
  2  Soft watch                        2 
  3  Dali                              1 
  4  Narciss                           1 
  5  The Woman In Green                0 
  6  A summer in Vetheuil              0 
  7  Artist's Garden                   2 
  8  Beech Forest                      2 
  9  Claude Monet                      0
```

Comment: Do you want to get the latest row from the table? The last row in the table(to be more precise).

Comment: Since an ID is (generally) unique, grouping by ID would create groups of 1.

Comment: Try replacing it with `GROUP BY test_id` and see what happens.

Comment: Why does the query not return the single row "9 Claude Monet 0"?

Comment: @Alastair: Because you grouped by `id`.  So for each unique `id` it will return the highest `id` in that group.  Since `id` is unique, each "group" contains 1 record.  The maximum for each group, then, is that record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of using `MAX()` the `GROUP BY` clause essentially tells the query engine how to group the items from which to determine a maximum.  In your first example you were selecting only a single column, so there was no need for grouping.  But in your second example you had multiple columns.  So you need to tell the query engine how to determine which ones are going to be compared to find a maximum.

You told it to group by the `id` column.  Which means that it's going to compare records which have the same `id` and give you the maximum one for each unique `id`.  Since every record has a different `id`, you essentially didn't do anything with that clause.

It grouped all records with an `id` of `1` (which was a single record), and returned the record with the maximum `id` from that group (which was that record).  It did the same for `2`, `3`, etc.

In the case of the three columns shown here, the only place where it would make sense to group your records would be on the `test_id` column.  Something like this:

```
SELECT MAX(id), title, test_id
FROM images
WHERE image IS NOT null 
GROUP BY test_id
```

This would group them by the `test_id`, so the results will include records 6 (the maximum `id` for `test_id` 0), 4 (the maximum `id` for `test_id` 1), and 8 (the maximum `id` for `test_id` 2).  By splitting the records into those three groups based on the three unique values in the `test_id` column, it can effectively find a "maximum" `id` within each group.

Comment: Thank you for assistance, I think @David's explanation is the most clear and concise.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in your example it serves no useful purpose.

You're grouping by ID then finding the maximum ID.  But that doesn't make sense since there's only one of each ID.  Normally MAX() is used on quantities, like prices or item counts or such like.

Answer (score 0):

Group by is not used for this kind of queries
Its is used for queries like this

```
OId OrderDate   OrderPrice  Customer

1   2008/11/12  1000    Hansen

2   2008/10/23  1600    Nilsen

3   2008/09/02  700 Hansen

4   2008/09/03  300 Hansen

5   2008/08/30  2000    Jensen

6   2008/10/04  100 Nilsen
```

Now if you want to get sum of material bought by each customer of these you will use group by

SELECT Customer,SUM(OrderPrice) FROM Orders
GROUP BY Customer

```
customer    SUM(OrderPrice)

Hansen  2000

Nilsen  1700

Jensen  2000
```

**In above case id is unique so group by id will not make any sense**