# how to get all version and latest iteration of object in the SQL

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm very new to SQL...

I have data like below in table called `versioniteration`. I want build a query in SQL (oracle) to get the out as in the second table. Please guide me how to do this?

Here the part get altered many times in given version, each time the changes made the iteration increases.

The part can also change to new version then the Iteration will be assigned (number).

```
| Name          | Version       | Iteration  |
|===============|===============|============|
| Part 1        |      A        |    1       |
|:------------------------------------------:|
| Part 1        |      A        |    2       |
|:------------------------------------------:|
| Part 1        |      A        |    3       |
|:------------------------------------------:|
| Part 1        |      B        |    0       |
|:------------------------------------------:|
| Part 1        |      B        |    1       |
|:------------------------------------------:|
| Part 1        |      B        |    2       |
|:------------------------------------------:|
| Part 2        |      D        |    1       |
|:------------------------------------------:|
| Part 2        |      D        |    2       |
|:------------------------------------------:|
| Part 2        |      D        |    3       |
|:------------------------------------------:|
| Part 2        |      C        |    0       |
|:------------------------------------------:|
| Part 2        |      C        |    1       |
|:------------------------------------------:|
| Part 2        |      C        |    2       |
|:------------------------------------------:|
```

The out should be:

```
| Name          | Version       | Iteration  |
|===============|===============|============|
| Part 1        |      A        |    3       |
|:------------------------------------------:|
| Part 1        |      B        |    2       |
|:------------------------------------------:|
| Part 2        |      C        |    2       |
|:------------------------------------------:|
| Part 2        |      D        |    3       |
|:------------------------------------------:|
```

Comment: This is a very basic `group by` query.

Comment: Plz explain how the grouping can help to pick the highest iteration value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How said Gordon Linoff is basic `group by` query. You should understand how work group by and add other features to query. For example, your task is `group by` + `MAX`. Also look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10690848/please-explain-the-functionality-of-select-max-group-by-in-sql).

Your query:

```
SELECT name
     , version
     , MAX(iteration)
FROM table1
GROUP BY name, version
```