# (Oracle) REGEXP_LIKE taking too long to lookup

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

I'm executing a query to find the right version and iteration of the data (see SQL below).

```
SELECT WTPartMaster.WTPARTNUMBER AS PartNumber ,
  WTPartMaster.name              AS "Name",
  wtpart.VERSIONIDA2VERSIONINFO 
  ||'.'
  || wtpart.ITERATIONIDA2ITERATIONINFO AS "Version",
  wtpart.ida2a2
FROM wtpart,
  WTPartMaster,
  (SELECT MAX(wp.branchIditerationInfo) AS MAX,
    wp.idA3masterReference
  FROM wtpart wp

  GROUP BY wp.idA3masterReference
  ) branchmax
WHERE wtpart.IDA3MASTERREFERENCE  = WTPartMaster.ida2a2
AND WTPartMaster.wtpartnumber = '07011796'
AND wtpart.LATESTITERATIONINFO    = 1
AND wtpart.branchiditerationinfo IN (branchmax.max)
ORDER BY PartNumber ;
```

when I add the condition to check if the column `WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(wp.VERSIONIDA2VERSIONINFO, '\.')` have more than one character or dot (.) it takes ~2sec to execute without that condition it takes ~0.2sec. Is there way I can improve the performance of this query?

I have tried `LENGTH` also.

```sql
SELECT WTPartMaster.WTPARTNUMBER AS PartNumber ,
  WTPartMaster.name              AS "Name",
  wtpart.VERSIONIDA2VERSIONINFO 
  ||'.'
  || wtpart.ITERATIONIDA2ITERATIONINFO AS "Version",
  wtpart.ida2a2
FROM wtpart,
  WTPartMaster,
  (SELECT MAX(wp.branchIditerationInfo) AS MAX,
    wp.idA3masterReference
  FROM wtpart wp
  where NOT REGEXP_LIKE(wp.VERSIONIDA2VERSIONINFO, '\.')
  GROUP BY wp.idA3masterReference
  ) branchmax
WHERE wtpart.IDA3MASTERREFERENCE  = WTPartMaster.ida2a2
AND WTPartMaster.wtpartnumber = '07011796'
AND wtpart.LATESTITERATIONINFO    = 1
AND wtpart.branchiditerationinfo IN (branchmax.max)
ORDER BY PartNumber ;
```

Comment: I haven't been working with oracle for a while but in my experience I tried alway avoid NOT when possible... Maybe it is better to write `where REGEXP_LIKE(wp.VERSIONIDA2VERSIONINFO, '[^\.]{2,}')`   (if I understand correctly what you want)

Comment: Could you please attach the `wtpart` table DDL ? I mean it could be normal to have higher runtime here it depends on data. Also it's not so eficient to use RegEx for so simple pattern. Try to use `INSTR` instead. Also it could have sence to look at both query execution plans attach them too.

Comment: @agent5566, you can find the sample of [DDL here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35353222/how-to-get-all-version-and-latest-iteration-of-object-in-the-sql/35356352#35356352).

Comment: i'm sorry but i don't see any ddl there @user3130446